# User environment separation clarification

Tags: users, multiuser

I need to have multiple environment on my laptop and I want to have them separated in the way that one user action can not break another user environment and so that the users can use different versions of same tool.

First option is multi-boot which brings more pain than pros. So probably I will utilize different users. But how much are they isolated.

Let's take docker-deamon like apps as example.
I guess the problem differs based on for whom the app is installed.

1. In case of docker(which needs root) the instalation will be system-wide and only option to run different docker is to install them twice.
2. In case the service is "user-wide" (let's say Podman) it will be started separated for each user, right? If I will log with second terminal/user it will run another separated Podman in two different user spaces, right?

So only the "under root" installed apps can break the separation between those environment.

Comment: Yes user environments are separated by default (with some exceptions on desktop installations to provide access to audio, video, wifi, bluetooth etc.). Point 2 is correct, and applies to most user apps. Regarding point 1, yes Docker runs system-wide. In fact users don't have access to Docker, only `root` does. Adding users to the docker group, [effectively](https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker.html) gives them root access, so it's not recommended unless you fully trust them. I'm not aware of any way to install Docker twice, and run it as a user. (Could be done through a VM.)

Comment: When it comes to daemons, many of them can be run as a user, but then they must listen on a higher port, because ports below 1024 are reserved for `root`.

Comment: You can also use VMs... a Linux VM built to run a specific app is fairly small and boots fast (what is slow and big is the desktop).

Comment: VM are the way I'm using so far. But there are some issues regarding networking, performance etc. Furthermore the full separation they provided, leads to need of reinstallation of common parts in each VM, which I though I can somehow overcome beeing able to use shared "system-wide" installs.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but I'm facing what @Zveratko said in his last comment:

"reinstallation of common parts in each VM, which I though I can somehow overcome being able to use shared "system-wide" installs."

I haven't set anything up yet but I want to use a collection of programs and there are several ways of putting them together, each using different resources, although there are a large set of common dependencies. So referring to the comment I quoted, what is a good way to set things up? All can use common libraries but can be compiled with different options, separately.